# Binding not appearing in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to bind my combobox itemsource to a collection.

```
public BindableCollection<NaicsCodeDTO> PriNaics { get; set; }
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PriNaics" ItemsSource="{Binding PriNaics}"/>
```

The Query

```
PriNaics = new BindableCollection<NaicsCodeDTO>(
           ctx.NaicsCodes.Where(x => x.Parent == null).Select(x => new NaicsCodeDTO{ Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }));
OnPropertyChanged("PriNaics");
```

When I check the combobox, It just shows the (NameSpace).NaicsCodeDTO, not the exact value.
What I tried:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PriNaics" ItemsSource="{Binding PriNaics.Name}"/>

NaicCodeDTO.cs:

public class NaicsCodeDTO : IDTO
{
    // Primary Key --------------------------------------------------------
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Fields -------------------------------------------------------------
    public int MinCode { get; set; }
    public int MaxCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm just wondering how do I fix the bindings, I think it's something very small and silly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **`DisplayMemberPath`** to **`Name`** property on comboBox:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PriNaics"
          ItemsSource="{Binding PriNaics}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

---

By default comboBox call ToString() on bound object which will print full name for your class. Hence you see `(NameSpace).NaicsCodeDTO` as an output.

With [**DisplayMemberPath**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx), you explicitly tell comboBox to bind with entire object but display Name property on UI.

> Gets or sets a path to a value on the source object to serve as the
>   visual representation of the object.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, THANK YOU!